# how to use speech_to_text plugin in flutter to print the data that is spoken by the user

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text

I have tried to use the speech_to_text plugin in the flutter. but I didn't quite understand the documentation

this is the code they have given

```
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

stt.SpeechToText speech = stt.SpeechToText();
bool available = await speech.initialize( onStatus: statusListener, onError: errorListener );

if (available) {
  speech.listen( onResult: resultListener );
} else {
  print('error occured i am unavailible');
}
speech.stop();
```

Could anyone please help me understand statusListener, errorListener, resultListener,
and how can I use this code to print the user's speech on the console?

Answer (score 0):

statusListener, errorListener, and resultListener are functions that will be executed when the status of the listening changes (statusListener), error occurs (errorListener), and success occurs (resultListener).

have you tried this example? https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text#-example-tab-

```
  String lastWords = "";
  String lastError = "";
  String lastStatus = "";

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      lastWords = "${result.recognizedWords} - ${result.finalResult}";
    });
    print(lastWords); //print the user's speech on the console
  }
  
  void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) {
    // print("Received error status: $error, listening: ${speech.isListening}");
    setState(() {
      lastError = "${error.errorMsg} - ${error.permanent}";
    });
  }

  void statusListener(String status) {
    // print("Received listener status: $status, listening: ${speech.isListening}");
    setState(() {
      lastStatus = "$status";
    });
  }
```

You can use **resultListener** to print the user's speech on the console